# How can you make a UIPageControl/UIScrollView loop around

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nstimer, uipagecontrol

I'm programmatically flicking through images by having a repeating `NSTimer` which when fires I set the page control's current page and the scroll view's `currentOffset`.

When I get to the last image I set the page control's current page back to `0` and the scroll view's `currentOffset` also back to `0`. However this has the effect of very quickly rewinding things backwards to the start rather than give the impression of going forward.
Is there a quick and easy way to do this other than use something like [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)?

Answer (score 1):

For any "infinite" scroll you only need it to show three items.

The previous item.
The current item.
The next item.

If you have an array with 5 items and you want it to scroll infinitely then you first show...

5, 1, 2 (the middle is always the current item).

If the user then swipes to view number 2 then as soon as it finishes scrolling you put number 2 into the middle like so...

1, 2, 3 and then change the offset of the view so that it is back in the middle.

i.e. you always move out and then back to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this ideal for your needs but you could add the first image to the end of the UIScrollView as well.

When you hit the last image, you can set the content offset of the scroll view back to 0 (without an animation) and update your page control.

Comment: I think something along these lines might work, but the trouble is without the animation there is a discontinuity in user experience (as the previous images are animated). So I tried setting the content offset to the last and duplicated image with animation first, then setting the content offset to 0 without animation. However that doesn't work, I'll do some more experiments though.

Comment: That's why you'd add the first image to the end of the scroll view as well, so when the content offset is set back to 0, the next image will be animated again

Comment: That's what I tried, it doesn't work. I will be able to get things to work if I continually add new subviews (while removing old ones) with an ever increasing frame i.e. the y value for the frame just increases and never goes back to 0. This will work, but if the limit of the range of integral values for y gets reached it'll need to roll back without the animation.

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with an ever increasing x content offset (that was a typo above when I said y), and also in parallel a variation of your approach with a duplicate at the start and the back for scrolling in both directions. I think your approach will work but first its necessary to scroll to the last item with animation and then only when that animation has finished scroll back to the beginning without animation. I'll provide updates once I have something satisfactory.